# RequireJS out-of-order execution - not honouring arguments to `require`

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

When building and running RequireJS with CoffeeScript in what I understand to be the ordinary way, I seem to have a problem with code not being executed in the expected order i.e.

```
<script src="/_s/lib/require-jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    paths: {
      "main": "/_s/all.min", // <--- the 'optimized' result of `$ r.js build.js`
    }
  });
  require(["main"], function () {
     // this executes without any regard to whether 'main' is loaded.
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     // also:
     // require('cs!csmain') throws an exception because "cs!csmain" has not been
     // loaded for context: '_'.
  });
```

One would expect the function passed to `require(["main"], ...` to be executed after main and all its dependencies are loaded, because [that's what the documentation says](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

However, that is not the case at all. On my local development system this problem does not exhibit itself, I suppose because it is a race condition of some sort, making it doubly problematic because this is cropping up only AFTER deployment/staging.

I have a straightforward `main.js` like this:

```
var _paths;

_paths = {
  ... 
  underscore: '../lib/lodash'
};

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/_s/mycode/', // main.js lives here
  paths: _paths,
  shim: {
     ...
    'timeago': ['jquery']
  },
  waitSeconds: 60
});

require(['cs!csmain']); // has all the dependencies
```

Along with a `build.js` called as an argument to `r.js` along the lines of:

```
({
    baseUrl:    'mycode',
    optimize:   'none',
    out:        'all.min.js',
    stubModules: ['cs', 'coffee-script'],
    paths: {
        ...
        underscore: '../lib/lodash'
    },
    name: 'main',
    shim: {
       ...
    }
})
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I really enjoy the asynchronous nature of RequireJS combined with the ability to split up my code into sensible modules, but this problem is particularly frustrating because it only exhibits on a staging/production setting.

Any thoughts and suggestions would be duly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Removed some probably-superfluous arguments to shorten the question.

Comment: Brian, do you have this code published on some site, so we can try to debug to see what is happening? Because looking at your configuration I don't see nothing wrong, maybe debugging...

Comment: @devundef: Thanks for the comment. I thought the code looked okay, too. :) After several hours of debugging, I have only just narrowed the problem down to the above. I can try and reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle, but need to take a break so I don't go crazy first. :)

Comment: Sometimes code can drive us crazy, don't they? :) Ok then, if you can reproduce the error in jsFiddle is even better.

Comment: @devundef: It's possible, per my answer below, that I sorted out the issue. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have sorted this problem out - `main.js` should contain a call to `define`, as I [posted in an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs/issues/26).

Comment: Wow, I always use a require inside my main module and this problem never happened. But makes more sense use define() instead of require(). Please let me know if this resolved.

Comment: @devundef: I always put `require` in my main modules too - I thought it was just the way to do it (and I vaguely recall `define` being problematic in `main.js` in some situations). I look forward to finding out whether what I've done is actually the 'right' solution.